# Can you uninitialize a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

i'm using Select2 jquery library to style my select elements. At a certain media query, i would like to remove the library and use the standard select element. Is it possible to uninitialize the jquery library at a certain media query?

```
$("#location").select2({});

$(window).on("resize", function() {
  var win = $(this);

if (win.width() <= 575) {
  // uninitialize select2
}

});
```

Comment: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#destroying-the-select2-control

Comment: amazing!! thank you for the quick response!

Comment: You can always assign `null` to a variae to let the garbage collector now you don't need a variable anymore

Comment: @MoritzRoessler that's true, but it won't remove the library's UI from the DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In select2 you can unbind using destroy

```
// Destroy location
$('#location').select2('destroy');
```

So in your example:

```
$("#location").select2({});

$(window).on("resize", function() {
  var win = $(this);

if (win.width() <= 575) {
      $('#location').select2('destroy');

}

});
```

Documentation: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods#destroying-the-select2-control

Comment: @juicyj no problem, if this answer worked for you can you accept it as an answer?